Cross-tenant Azure Blob Storage SAS fails with "Signature did not match" using UserDelegatedCredential and azure-sdk-for-go
My infrastructure setup is as follows:
There are two tenants - Tenant A and Tenant B.
In Tenant A, I have a resource group with a k8s cluster, a managed identity, a storage account with a container, and other resources. In Tenant B, I have a resource group with only a managed identity and a storage account with a container.
I can successfully write from an app running in the k8s cluster in Tenant A to the storage container in Tenant B. I am able to do this because in Tenant B, I gave Storage Account Contributor and Storage Blob Data Owner roles to the managed identity in the same resource group. Then, I created a federated credential that allows the k8s cluster in tenant A to auth to the managed identity in tenant B, by using the following command:
az identity federated-credential create \
  --name fc-x-tenant-test \
  --identity-name tenantB-managedIdentity \
  --resource-group tenantB-rg \
  --issuer <Tenant A AKS Cluster OIDC Provider URL> \
  --subject system:serviceaccount:default:<Tenant A Service Account name>

(I followed https://paulyu.dev/article/cross-tenant-workload-identity-on-aks/ to set this up - thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/21008480/pauldotyu !)
Then, using azure-sdk-for-go, I create a client (I check err != nil, but leaving out here for simplicity)
url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName)
opts := &azidentity.WorkloadIdentityCredentialOptions{
    TenantID: *tenantBID,
    ClientID: *tenantBmanagedIdentityClientID,
}
cred, err := azidentity.NewWorkloadIdentityCredential(opts)
client, err := azblob.NewClient(url, cred, nil)
serviceClient := client.ServiceClient()
containerClient := serviceClient.NewContainerClient(containerName)


From there, I can successfully read and write to the container. Note: I need to specify the tenantID and managed identity client ID from Tenant B when I create the credential, otherwise the SDK would try to authenticate with the Tenant A - the tenant that the AKS Cluster is in!

However, when I try to generate a pre-signed URL for a client to be able to PUT objects to this container, it does not work. The signed URL looks like this https://<Tenant B Storage Account Name>.blob.core.windows.net/<Tenant B Container Name>/path/to/object/metadata.json?se=2024-05-03T01%3A33%3A10Z&sig=KL3t1EGRODo4%2FUUu5Irtaw11vXwIEpBkO2sYTqrTg5o%3D&sp=w&spr=https&sr=b&sv=2023-11-03.
And I get back a 403 error with
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
authenticationerrordetail:Signature did not match

I create the pre-signed URL with the following code (using a client created as shown above, with Tenant B's tenantID and managed identity Client ID).
serviceClient := client.ServiceClient()
now := time.Now().UTC().Add(-10 * time.Second)
expiry := now.Add(24 * time.Hour)
info := azblobService.KeyInfo{
    Start:  to.Ptr(now.UTC().Format(sas.TimeFormat)),
    Expiry: to.Ptr(expiry.UTC().Format(sas.TimeFormat)),
}
udc, err := serviceClient.GetUserDelegationCredential(ctx, info, nil)
sigVals := sas.BlobSignatureValues{
    Protocol:      sas.ProtocolHTTPS,
    ExpiryTime:    time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour).UTC(),
    Permissions:   perm.String(),
    ContainerName: containerName,
    BlobName:      blobName,
}
query, err := sigVals.SignWithUserDelegation(udc)

I then call query.Encode() while generating the signed URL.
I was able to log the value of query it is here below. The two fields with  are redacted, but the description describes what values were there.
Query {
    version:2023-11-03 
    services: 
    resourceTypes: 
    protocol:https 
    startTime:{wall:0 ext:0 loc:<nil>} 
    expiryTime:{wall:151009920 ext:63850466819 loc:<nil>} 
    snapshotTime:{wall:0 ext:0 loc:<nil>} 
    ipRange:{Start:[] End:[]} 
    identifier: 
    resource:b 
    permissions:w 
    signature:bDcn0MCs1kGakVX9OOtKt/ApBllv68AJLZnwZK4g+5g= 
    cacheControl: contentDisposition: contentEncoding: contentLanguage: contentType: 
    signedOID:<Tenant B Managed Identity Object ID> 
    signedTID:<Tenant B Tenant ID> 
    signedStart:{wall:0 ext:63850380409 loc:<nil>} 
    signedService:b 
    signedExpiry:{wall:0 ext:63850466809 loc:<nil>} 
    signedVersion:2023-11-03 
    signedDirectoryDepth: authorizedObjectID: unauthorizedObjectID: correlationID: encryptionScope: stTimeFormat: seTimeFormat:
}

Here I noticed the expiry times look strange. However, I validated the expiryTime is okay, because I was able to get SAS working all in Tenant A using shared access keys, and its expiryTime was set that way.
The signed start/expiry times also looked off at first. So I logged the values and they looked right. Then I tried to see what would happen if I made it so the signedStart would equal {wall:0 ext:0 loc:<nil>}, and the issue persisted. (You can see what all of these values mean at Create a user delegation SAS
.)
I also enabled logs for the target storage account in Tenant B, and I can see successful PutBlob, GetBlob, and DeleteBlob calls in the $logs container (for cross-tenant reads/writes that don't use SAS). However, I don't see any logs for the failed SAS PUTs that keep getting rejected.
EDIT: update, I now have reproduced the same issue with everything in a single tenant

The issue was that I cannot specify BlobName in the BlobSignatureValues when signing with a UserDelegationCredential.
However, you can specify BlobName there when I use a SharedKeyCredential and sign with SignWithSharedKey
